# Why react function component execute internal code twice when initial rendering ？

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code:

```
// App.js
import { useEffect } from "react";

let count1 = 0;
function App() {
  console.log("render");
  console.log("before", count1);
  count1 += 1;
  useEffect(() => console.log("effect", count1));
  console.log("after", count1);

  return <button></button>;
}

export default App;

// index.js
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

After initial rendering, The console result in Chrome is:

[image]

I don't know why the value of `count1` is `2` at last.

Comment: It is because you use the `Hook` `useEffect`. And this by default runs both after the first render and after every update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the `StrictMode` wrapper that has been used in your `index.js` probably.

You can read about it [here in the doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html).

This is a feature provided for developers to diagnose bugs more easily, and as it's been said in the doc:

> Strict mode checks are run in development mode only; they do not
> impact the production build.

If you do not like this feature, you can remove it from your projects and as you can see [here in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-cache-6ci4x?file=/src/index.js:173-183), it's rendering once now after I commented Strictmode.